# How to get each value in a column of database in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't have enough knowledge about this criteria:

I want to loop inside the for each loop to get all values in a particular column.

For example: I got the values from DB through `get_result` and store the result in `$results`.

After that use:

```
for each($results as $result)
❴
    $output = $result->message
❵
```

Where `message` is a column in DB.

I want to loop over all the messages instead of storing last one by replacing.

Can you please give me suggestions on how to loop inside `for each`?

Comment: Please give an example of your output you want from this? Do you want to return a single string or an array?

Comment: I want to return a single string by looping,for eg:if the column message contains values ABC,Tre,like I want to return each one without overriding previous one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output[] = $result ->message;
```

Now `$output` will contain all messages on index 0, 1, 2 ...

You are facing the issue because:

```
$output=$result ->message;
```

the above line is present inside the loop, and each new iteration onerride the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just looking for foreach inside foreach then you can try the following.

```
 <?php 
    foreach($results as $result){
        $output=$result->message;
        foreach($output as $messages){
            echo $messages;
        }
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the message into another variable. You can do whatever you need to do inside the loop. For example, if you are displaying the messages, you can get it done inside the loop:

```
foreach ($results AS $result) {

   echo $results->message . "<br>";

}
```